# how to remove a sequence from string in ftl

Tags: java, freemarker

I am working on a project where I need to put away some part of string, not to be visible on front page.
I am working with ftl.

Example:

there is a string like:

```
<#assign valueToShow= "#99#testing,#777#test">
```

I need to show the values without part **#digits#**.
The final result need to be like this:

```
"testing,test"
```

How can I do that in FTL?

Thanks...

Comment: What have you tried and provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`valueToShow?replace("#[0-9]+#", "", "r")`, where 3rd `"r"` parameter means that what you replace is a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

The string class offers an easy way to do this:

```
String valueToShow = rawString.replaceFirst("#\\d+#", "")
```